# Games freeze after a while on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, games, performance

I recently installed Lubuntu, and decided to install a few games, but they freeze after 2-5 minutes of playing. But after exiting the console by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> and then returning back pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> the game starts working again - and later it freezes again.

I searched a bunch of forums without finding the reason.

Maybe somebody knows how to fix it?

My system specs are:

- Processor: Intel Pentium E2160 1.8 GHz
- RAM: 2GB
- GPU: Intel GMA 3000 256MB

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Care to provide some more information? Which games? Are you just playing or doing other activities (like browsing the web) while they run?

Comment: @MrShunz Counter Strike 1.6 and Crypt of the Necrodancer. I'm not browsing, just playing.